# Recursive Flood Fill in an image using python and numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, flood-fill

I'm working on a project based on feature extraction from images, I'm using python with numpy and I don't want to import any other functions from libraries.
I wrote a recursive implementation of flood fill algorithm, the aim of this algorithm is to start from the center of a mole and flood fill it, for simplicity I'm working on the matrix of labels. Since the mole has some little holes inside and I want to remove them I'm actually coloring all the pixels which has 4 out of 8 neighbors with the color of the mole, this is also smoothing edges which is a good thing to my purposes.
This is my function

```
    def flood_fill(self, posi, posj, targetcolor, color):
        """
            recursive function to flood fill the mole starting from its centroids.


        """
        if(posi==-1 or posj == -1 or posi == self.N1 or posj == self.N2):
            return


        if(self.labels[posi][posj] == color):
            return

        if(self.labels[posi][posj] != targetcolor):
            c=0
            if(self.labels[posi+1][posj] == targetcolor or self.labels[posi+1][posj] == color):
                c+=1
            if(self.labels[posi][posj+1] == targetcolor or self.labels[posi][posj+1] == color):
                c+=1    
            if(self.labels[posi-1][posj] == targetcolor or self.labels[posi-1][posj] == color):
                c+=1
            if(self.labels[posi][posj-1] == targetcolor or self.labels[posi][posj-1] == color):
                c+=1
            if(self.labels[posi+1][posj+1] == targetcolor or self.labels[posi+1][posj+1] == color):
                c+=1
            if(self.labels[posi+1][posj-1] == targetcolor or self.labels[posi+1][posj+1] == color):
                c+=1
            if(self.labels[posi-1][posj-1] == targetcolor or self.labels[posi-1][posj-1] == color):
                c+=1
            if(self.labels[posi-1][posj+1] == targetcolor or self.labels[posi-1][posj+1] == color):
                c+=1
            if(c >= 4):
                self.labels[posi][posj] = color
            return



        self.labels[posi][posj] == color

        if(posi>self.maxi):
            self.maxi = posi
        if(posj>self.maxj):
            self.maxj = posj
        if(posi<self.mini):
            self.mini = posi
        if(posj<self.minj):
            self.minj = posj



        self.flood_fill(posi-1, posj, targetcolor, color, count+1)
        self.flood_fill(posi+1, posj, targetcolor, color, count+1)   
        self.flood_fill(posi, posj-1, targetcolor, color, count+1)
        self.flood_fill(posi, posj+1, targetcolor, color, count+1)    
        self.flood_fill(posi+1, posj+1, targetcolor, color, count+1)
        self.flood_fill(posi-1, posj+1, targetcolor, color, count+1)
        self.flood_fill(posi+1, posj-1, targetcolor, color, count+1)
        self.flood_fill(posi-1, posj-1, targetcolor, color, count+1)





        return
```

I cannot understand what's wrong with my code and why it doesn't work, spyder stop the execution without any message, I tried increasing the recursion limit but I think the problem it's not that. I'm new to python language but I know recursion and the termination conditions seems adequate to me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's *count*? Where does it come from? What is it used for? Why is *flood_fill()* declared with 4 parameters but called with 5?

Comment: Count is just a parameter i forgot,. I used it to force the recursion to stop, it's the recursion depth –

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to explain the code better if you wish anyone to help. No inline comments, no explanation of the various variables (what's N1, N2, what are maxi and maxj for, etc.) Kindly comment the code so someone who is willing to help will not have to waste time trying to figure out what you could have easily explained. Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

`self.flood_fill(posi-1, posj, targetcolor, color, count+1)` here you are passing an extra parameter `count+1` but your declared function definition only has first 4 parameters. This does not look like recursion. 
check this out. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flood-fill-algorithm-implement-fill-paint/

Comment: Count is just a parameter i forgot,. I used it to force the recursion to stop, it's the recursion depth